# How to change a variable in a service with AJAX? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, callback

I'm trying to use AJAX to bring in some data and then modify it before sending the result to a controller. I had this all working in the controller but I was told that it's better to do it in a service.

```
app.factory('GameweekJsonFactory', ['$http',function($http){
            var promise;
            var service = {
                async: function() {
                    if ( !promise ) {
                        promise = $http.get('jsons/gameweeks.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data
                        });
                    }
                return promise;
                }
            }
            return service;
        }]);
```

Then in another factory I wanted to change the value of a variable dependent on the response of the AJAX call. (Say for example if it's gameweek 6 going by date, I want gwk to equal 6).

```
app.factory('GameweekFactory',['GameweekJsonFactory',function(GameweekJsonFactory) {
   var gwk;
   var obj = {
       foo: function(){
            GameweekJsonFactory.async().then(function(d){
                //Code here to find out the current gameweek.
                gwk = 6;
                return gwk;
            });
        }
    };
    return gwk;
}]);


controller: function(GameweekFactory){
            console.log('Controller Log '+GameweekFactory)
},
```

How do I then modify the original gwk variable in the factory's scope? I can't work it out and I've been googling for ages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining the factory correctly. AngularJS factories are functions that return a value, and in this case it's an object with a method named `foo`.

Promises are chainable. The value returned by a success callback is passed into the next success callback. So you can manipulate the value (add gwk) and return that value.

```
app.factory('GameweekFactory',[
    'GameweekJsonFactory',
    function(GameweekJsonFactory) {
        return {
            foo: function(){
                return GameweekJsonFactory.async().then(function(d){
                    //Code here to find out the current gameweek.
                    d.gwk = 6;
                    return d;
                });
        }
    };
}]);


controller: function(GameweekFactory){
    GameweekFactory.foo().then(function(d){
        console.log('Controller Log '+d.gwk)
    });
}
```

Comment: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' in the controller doing it like this? Why is foo returning undefined?

Comment: Changed a bit of formatting elsewhere and got it working now, thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, foo should return the promise to continue the chain.